# Set same height in flex-box for dynamic content

Tags: html, css, height, flexbox, flexboxgrid

In this case

- need to keep same height for all three columns (this is working already according to current code, ".col" get same height using flex)
- need to set max height of yellow div (dynamic content) for all yellow
  div
- need to be implement using CSS only (not JavaScript)
- use flex (not tables)

here is test code [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tharakanilupul/hyLqqkuj/)

**Current Design**
[image: current design here]
**Need Design**
[image: need design]

I have dynamic content inside the "bottom-content" area. what I need to do, set all "bottom-content" area same height (set max height for 3 yellow areas), and all "col" should be same height too.

**HTML code**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="col">
         <div class="top-content">top content here</div>
         <div class="bottom-content">bottom content here</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
         <div class="top-content">top content here</div>
         <div class="bottom-content">bottom content here</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
         <div class="top-content">top content here</div>
         <div class="bottom-content">bottom content here</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS code**

```
.container {      
  display: -webkit-flex;        
  display: -ms-flexbox;     
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.container .col {
  flex: 1;
  padding: 20px;
}
.container .col:nth-child(1) { 
  background: #eee; 
}
.container .col:nth-child(2) { 
  background: #ccc;
}
.container .col:nth-child(3) { 
  background: #eee;
}
.top-content {
  background: #888;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #333;
  padding: 5px;
}
.bottom-content {
  background: yellow;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

Comment: I have referred [guide to flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) to get to know about flex.

Comment: another test [code](https://jsfiddle.net/tharakanilupul/qunqo2st/) for to set yellow div same height